# Replace multiple instances of a character within matching group

Tags: regex, hive

I'm trying to write a regexp_replace to replace comma (,) separator within square brackets with semi-colon (;).

**Input string:**

```
gc:network,sm:Out of stock,fm:[PUT,Free store pickup today,S2H],pb:[Rollback,Test]
```

**Expected output:**

```
gc:network,sm:Out of stock,fm:[PUT;Free store pickup today;S2H],pb:[Rollback;Test]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How many bracketed terms can appear in the CSV string?

Comment: One to five is what I’ve seen in my data till now

Comment: Use `"(\\G(?!^)|\\[)([^,\\]\\[]*),"`  and replace with `"$1$2;"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the output has some issues, it's eliminating the 2nd delimiter and adding an extra at the beginning. here's the output: `gc:network,sm:Out of stock,fm:[;PUT;Free store pickup todayS2H],pb:[Rollback;Test]`

Comment: It can't, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3KBAAM/1). You must have lost part of the regex or replacement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the demo seems perfect. I guess hive version that I've doesn't support it. I'm getting error `FAILED: ParseException line 10:105 cannot recognize input near '$' '1' '$' in select expression` when trying to execute this `regexp_replace(str,'(\\G(?!^)|\\[)([^,\\]\\[]*),','$1$2;')`

Answer (score 0):

If your regex supports lookahead and lookbehind, you can try:

```
(?<=\[[^\]]*),(?=[^\[]*\])
```

See here: [regexr](http://regexr.com/3v55a), there is also an explanation of the regex.

As mentioned in the comments, Java does not support infinite width lookbehind. You could possibly set the input length as limit, e.g. if it were 1000, this will work:

```
(?<=\[[^\]]{0,1000}),(?=[^\[]*\])
```

Comment: It says [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) that Hive's `regexp_replace` uses Java regex syntax, and AFAIK, Java regex engine doesn't support infinite width Lookbehinds.

Comment: Ok. Thanks!  I guess you could set the input length as a limit. E.g. `(?<=\[[^\]]{0,10000}),(?=[^\[]*\])` works in Java.

Comment: @ArunC Great that it works for you! :) Please consider to accept the answer, as this is part of how this platform works.

Comment: @morja I did soon after I tested the solution. Since I've less than 15 reputation points, the platform doesn't show the +1 from me.

Comment: @ArunC Ok :) I did not know that. I thought you should at least be able to accept the answer. But it's all good. Just wanted to mention it.